# Hybrid GPU Black Screen LINUX MINT 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, uefi, ssd, hybrid-graphics

I've installed **LINUX MINT 19.2 (Tina)** but when i try to login the screen get black and only the cursor is shown, not even the login chime is heard as seen in other sources. When I try to use the terminal before login, the screen simply "hangs" and i cannot even login anymore.
Having this in mind I searched several forums to try to solve, tried to reinstall several times but always unsuccessfully, unfortunately I can not send error log because it is impossible to access terminal.
Some facts that I consider important to be informed:

- My Config

  - CPU

    - Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
  - RAM

    - 16GB
  - GPU

    - Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (integrated)
    - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (integrated)
  - Storage:

    - SSD Micron 1100 MTFDDAV256TBN 256GB
  - Facts:
  - After login the screen get black and only cursor is shown
  - Any try to open terminal end in screen hanging
  - Live CD works
  - After installation (remove media and restart) screen hangs
  - UEFI
  - Already tried with flags nouveau.noaccel=1 and nomodeset
  - Tried Ubuntu, Debian, Kubuntu...
  - Used Balena Etcher and Rufus to create the bootable iso's

I will be extremely grateful if someone with experience can help me solve this problem (using Mint)!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 to enter the Terminal and install the propetary Nvidia driver. If you just disable Noveau without installing the Nvidia drivers first, it won't work. If hitting Ctrl+Alt+F2 doesn't work for you, you could try to install the drivers from chroot via your working Live-Media.

Comment: i install the latest nvidia driver in live before install, i should not get this same driver after installation?

Comment: I didn't read in topic, that you installed the propetary nvidia driver, you wrote only about noveau. If you have installed the nvidia driver, you could check via: lspci -nnk   which driver is in use at the moment. Also it depends on what you want. If you want the Opensource driver, you should go with the noveau driver, if you want max. performance, for example because you want to play games etc. I'd go with the propetary Nvidia driver

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention... anyway i can't use terminal (only in live cd), i will try install Mint 18 (to change the kernel) as a last try.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, you can access your Mint 19.2 installation via Live USB and chroot. don't be afraid, to try. there are plenty of online tutorials on how to chroot into your local installation. And I am afraid, another kernel will not help you tough, since your problem is probably with the graphics driver.

Comment: Well, logged with 4.15.0-20 and everything worked, only the freeze at poweroff/shutdown remains, but i updated all drivers, rebooted (with hard reset) and now 100% working.
I hope still working after 4.15.0-70.79

Answer (score 0):

Finally its worked, i have done theses steps, i hope that help someone else too:

- Instead of booting usually, use the "advanced options" option to boot with an older kernel (in this case using the 19 Tara kernel).
- When logging in be sure to go to "drivers" and select the correct NVIDIA® driver, after that you can update everything normally!

  - Note: On first restart after all this, the computer crashed again, being forced to give a "hard reset" but after updating everything started to work correctly.

[image: Boot options]
[image: Advanced options]